Return NA for conditional lead/lagged rolling sum if window outside dataframe or group
I need to get the sum of values from column x either side of every 1 in column y. The windows are 1:4 and 5:8 before and after each occurrence of 1 in y. However, if the windows are beyond the limits of the df, 0 is returned. This is an issue as it is possible that 0 could be a valid result. The full data have multiple groups (id) but hopefully this repex is enough help create a scalable solution.
I have never used zoo before so was unable to work out how to incorporate na.rm = TRUE and return NA where the window is completely outside the extent of the df. Solutions do not have to use zoo, but I would prefer verb-based answers if possible.
Data and packages:
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(id = rep("A", 40),
                 x = sample(0:3, 40, replace = TRUE),
                 y = 0)

df[c(2, 8, 9, 30, 33, 39), "y"] <- 1

What I tried:
w <- 4

df %>%
  mutate(bf2 = ifelse(y == 1, rollapply(lag(x, 5), width = w, sum, fill = NA, align = "right", partial = TRUE, na.rm = TRUE), NA),
         bf1 = ifelse(y == 1, rollapply(lag(x, 1), width = w, sum, fill = NA, align = "right", partial = TRUE, na.rm = TRUE), NA),
         af1 = ifelse(y == 1, rollapply(lead(x, 1), width = w, sum, fill = NA, align = "left", partial = TRUE, na.rm = TRUE), NA),
         af2 = ifelse(y == 1, rollapply(lead(x, 5), width = w, sum, fill = NA, align = "left", partial = TRUE, na.rm = TRUE), NA)) %>%
  filter(y == 1)

  id x y bf2 bf1 af1 af2
1  A 3 1   0   0   3   6
2  A 2 1   5   3   6   1
3  A 1 1   5   5   5   2
4  A 1 1   2   1   5   7
5  A 0 1   1   3   8   4
6  A 1 1   5   7   1   0

Desired output:
  id x y bf2 bf1 af1 af2
1  A 3 1  NA   0   3   6
2  A 2 1   5   3   6   1
3  A 1 1   5   5   5   2
4  A 1 1   2   1   5   7
5  A 0 1   1   3   8   4
6  A 1 1   5   7   1  NA


Your problem is not clear to me.  For any y == 1 we should sum which / how many x's? It may be easier if we first focus on one window size and ** one** direction (the others can be then done accordingly), this would help to understand the problem much better, b/c you are saying something like windows are 1:4 (1,2,3  and 4) but in your example you use width = 4 and lag = 5 whihc is totally confusing. so maybe re-write your problem with a simpler case.

You could always add checks to your conditions:
df %>%
  mutate(bf2 = ifelse(y & row_number() > 5, rollapply(lag(x, 5), width = w, sum, fill = NA, align = "right", partial = TRUE, na.rm = TRUE), NA),
         bf1 = ifelse(y & row_number() > 1, rollapply(lag(x, 1), width = w, sum, fill = NA, align = "right", partial = TRUE, na.rm = TRUE), NA),
         af1 = ifelse(y & row_number() + 1 <= n(), rollapply(lead(x, 1), width = w, sum, fill = NA, align = "left", partial = TRUE, na.rm = TRUE), NA),
         af2 = ifelse(y & row_number() + 5 <= n(), rollapply(lead(x, 5), width = w, sum, fill = NA, align = "left", partial = TRUE, na.rm = TRUE), NA)) |>
         filter(y == 1)

Output:
  id x y bf2 bf1 af1 af2
1  A 3 1  NA   0   3   6
2  A 2 1   5   3   6   1
3  A 1 1   5   5   5   2
4  A 1 1   2   1   5   7
5  A 0 1   1   3   8   4
6  A 1 1   5   7   1  NA

